# SQL data query - displaying count correctly

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2014

I have an SQL database that has log data of machines and users that use a piece of software.
i need to create a query that i can display all connections on a certain day (today) and group them by their Year level.

WindowsLogs Table:

```
Date
Time
Username
Year
AppV
IPaddress
MAC
DeviceName
Antivirus
5gigCompat
```

This is as far as i got:

```
select WindowsLogs.Year,count(*)
From WindowsLogs
Where WindowsLogs.Date=cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 105) as datetime)
group by WindowsLogs.Year
```

i currently get this:

```
Year | no name
   7 |  5
   8 |  2
  11 |  3
```

But ideally i want the data displayed like this:

```
Year 07 | XX
Year 08 | XX
Year 09 | XX
Year 10 | XX
Year 11 | XX
Year 12 | XX
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using, the best solution depends on it.

Comment: i am running SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you seem to want a `left join`, something like this:

```
select v.str, count(wl.year)
from (values ('Year 07', 7),
             ('Year 08', 8),
             ('Year 09', 9),
             ('Year 10', 10),
             ('Year 11', 11),
             ('Year 12', 12)
     ) v(str, yr) left join
     WindowsLogs wl
     on wl.date = convert(date, getdate()) and
        wl.year = v.yr
group by v.str
order by v.str;
```

Comment: i get this:Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'v.str' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Change to `GROUP BY v.str`

Comment: now:
Year 07 0
Year 08 0
Year 09 0
Year 10 0
Year 11 0
Year 12 0

Comment: @CurtisHealy . . . Based on your sample data, you should be getting matches.  Just be sure that the second column in `v` matches what you are called `year` in your data.

Answer (score 0):

fixed this by using the following:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfTransactions 
FROM WindowsLogs
WHERE WindowsLogs.Date=cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 105) as datetime) 
and WindowsLogs.Year = 7) as Year7today;
```

and continued for each year level

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT` and `FORMAT`

```
SELECT CONCAT("YEAR ", FORMAT(WindowsLogs.Year, "00")), FORMAT(COUNT(*), "00")
FROM WindowsLogs
WHERE WindowsLogs.Date=cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 105) as datetime)
GROUP BY WindowsLogs.Year
```